# Is there a callback for setting text in a UITextField in code?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to detect if a UITextField's text is set in code. e.g. I need a callback for `someTextField.text = "Some Text"`. I don't want to register the notification for `.editingChanged` as this will also be called every single time the user types something. It should **only** be called when the value is set in code.

Is there a way to do this? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Actually you are supposed to *know* when the text is set ***in code***

Comment: @Kex may be you can use keyboard hide show notification to achieve this, not sure.

Comment: There is no simple way to do it, subclass or pose as in Objective C, UITextField is not KVO compliant as far as I know...

Comment: @Kex did my answer help you??

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the textfields .isEmpty method so

```
if someTextField.isEmpty { 
    //do something 
}
```

Comment: That would only work is the textfield was empty in the first place and it will also be called when the user changes the textfield from empty to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the text var in `UITextField` by subclassing

```
class ObservableTextField: UITextField {

    var action : (()->Void)?

    override var text: String?{
        didSet{
            action?()
        }
    }

}
```

**Use**

```
@IBOutlet weak var obsTextField: ObservableTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    obsTextField.action = {
        debugPrint("changed")
    }
}
```

Comment: That will also be called when the user changes the text.

Comment: In fact this will only work with a code modification of the text property @DávidPásztor